# Android view over a view

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to get below result:

[image]

I need `LinearLayout` to appear on `MapView`

mapview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAcceptMyLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Onayla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelMyLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="İptal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u need to over right Map fragment ? or u need one more layout under MAP fragment ?

Comment: Post your map layout xml alone and explain your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your LinearLayout and MapView into a RelativeLayout. Align your LinearLayout to parent bottom.

Set MapView to fill parent width and height, set your LinearLayout width to fill parent, and height to something like 50dp (assuming your picture). Then use this option in your LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/mapView"
```